# Dynamically add/remove websockets chat instances

Tags: php, websocket, ratchet

I'm using **ratchet php** websockets and successfully connected to a port and echoed messages across terminals. My doubt is how can I create multiple instances of different chats and handle them? I'm using port **8080** for my test but if a user is using 10 different chats with different people in them how exactly should I work each chat? A different port for each one of them?

Comment: No different ports. Just one server on one port which is able to handle different chats. Think about createchat(), joinchat() and deletechat() methods

Comment: Hm... does that scale well? I'm talking about literally one million instances. Is there anything like port overflow?

Comment: I am not shure if you should use php for one million instances. But thats the way such servers work normally.